# Write SQL statement to look up row by join id, and insert a value from the joined row into the parent table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table called `Form` that contains a `User_id` that links to the `User` table.

I want to pull out the username from the user table, and insert it into a new field, `Form.ownersUsername`. I don't want to manually generate the insert statements myself, but get it to loop through all the fields and set the value `Form.ownersUsername` equal to the value of `User.username`.

I know how to join & select the tables so my I have all the relevant information selected using the below statement, but not sure on my next step.

```
SELECT * FROM Form
LEFT JOIN User U ON Form.id = U.id;
```

Thanks

```
Form table
-----------------------------------------------------
| Form_id |  title  |  Owner_id  |  Owner_username  |
|    1    |    x    |      1     |      <null>      | 
|    2    |    y    |      1     |      <null>      | 
 ----------------------------------------------------

User table
------------------------
| User_id |  username  |
|    1    |   000001   |
|    2    |   000002   |
------------------------
```

For reference: *I have to do this as my system creates a new user entry if the user details changes (they get promoted for example) as we need to know the details of the user at a point in time however when searching, we want to search by force number, not user entry.*

Comment: Please share sample data of the relevant tables and desired results so we can better understand.

Comment: Please TAG your specific RDBMS

Comment: So you know how to join the user name, that's all you need. Don't actually store the name in the other table, keep things normalized. For convenience you can create a view with the query with the join though.

Comment: What you are asking for is not a good idea and most definitely an anti-pattern; consider what happens if someone updates the `username` column in one table - now you have contradicting data, which is correct? Use a *view* instead.

Comment: Once done, I'd remove the link to the user table completely. It was an oversight of another developer to link that table, as due to the way users are configured, can cause errors with the search.

Comment: What you should do is 1) remove Owner_username column from Form.Owner_username 2) use this query to SELECT your data: `SELECT Form.title, User.username FROM Form LEFT JOIN User ON Form.Owner_id = User.User_id` -- this should give you the information you are looking for

Comment: Just like you said. It's better to Form table just keep only `Owner_id` since you can get username by joining Form table User table.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to update the rows that have a matching user Id

```
update f set
  f.Owner_username=u.username
from Form f
join [User] u ON = u.id = f.id;
```

This should probably be an *inner* join unless you wish to update all non-matching rows as NULL also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select statement for define value you want to insert. Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO Form (Owner_id, Owner_username)
SELECT
    User_id,
    username
FROM User
WHERE id = 2
```

This query will insert to columns `Owner_id` and `Owner_username` based on select result